# connecting two routers, each connected to a different ISP

Tags: routing, router, subnet, isp, architecture

I have two routers, one wireless connected to ISP1 with optical cable, and the second one connected to ISP2.
The second router is cisco 860 series, i will configure ACL lists and zone based firewall on it, so it need to be the router connected to the switch.
How do i connect the two routers to share same network? Is internet from two providers going to be in a single network (speed up)?
Do i need a third device to do this?

[image]

Actually want to apply this architecture, i don't know if it is possible, Even with a load balancer i can't keep internet from two providers?

Comment: According to your question. I understood your topology.  `R1`<--Net1-->`ISP1` and `R2`<---Net2-->`ISP2`.  `"Is internet from two providers going to be in a single network"`=>No, that is not possible. 

`"so it need to be the router connected to the switch"`=> where do you connect the swtich?? Im thinking this(http://www.omnisecu.com/images/tcpip/nat-overload-pat-topology.jpg) topology with 2 router and ISPs . Can you be more specific about your question.

Comment: I commented by an answer so i could add a screenshot! Thank you

Comment: You can do this, but you won't get additional bandwidth. You will either use one ISP or the other. Additionally, you need to decide what events would make you want to switch from one to the other.

Comment: I want to use the cisco router to filter traffic.

Comment: It may be possible to share the connections, so that PC0 uses one ISP and PC1 uses the other.  This may cause some problems when multiple sessions to a web site are coming from different IP addresses.

Comment: First of all, it is not a recommend approch. The `Router1` and `RouterCisco` are supposed to connect via switch not directly. May be you can try `HSRP` protocol or `GLBP` protocol to share the load balancing, i dont know that possible ro not. (`HSRP Concept:` You have to pick `virtual IP` in between subnet of  `Router1` and `RouterCisco`)

Comment: I agree with @RonTrunk, this should be workable by using Policy Routing, or something similar to ensure that, in nominal mode, each of the PCs uses one of the ISPs. You can also buy devices that embed this sort of "WAN Load Balancing" functionality (a lot of the UTM appliances like Fortinets or Checkpoints support this for example). That would probably be the easiest if adding a device is an option for you, as that will best handle redundancy, weighted load balancing if your links are of different types, etc...

Comment: I would think that if you want to use the features of the Cisco router, you would connect both ISPs to it, rather than use two routers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a load balancer device.  The load balancer will become your hosts' Gateway.  The purpose of the load balacer is to route traffics (based on a selected algorithm) to the ISPs.

One powerful open source load balancer is [Zen Loadbalancer](https://www.zenloadbalancer.com/community/downloads/).  You can even install it on a Virtual Machine.